# C# Асинхронный TCP сервер максимальная скорость обработки запроса?

Tags: c#, tcp

Есть асинхронный TCP сервер сделан по примеру кода от Microsoft который использует SocketAsyncEventArgs и на обычном (не серверный) ПК он держит примерно 16000 сокетов и обрабатывает примерно 10 запросов (на глаз) в секунду. Почему я не могу открыть больше чем "примерно 16000 сокетов" это ограничение Windows 10? (я пытался соединить больше чем 16000 сокетов и в этот момент Google Chrome переставал грузить страницу в интернете (но интернет не исчезал), не хватало сокетов?) и на глаз 10 запросов в секунду это скорость асинхронного потока? или что? посылать я могу несколько десятков тысяч запросов, но получаю +- 10 в секунду (добавляя в ObservableCollection с синхронизацией) и процессор вообще не напрягается, можно ли добавить скорости?

> **Server**

```
// Implements the connection logic for the socket server.  
// After accepting a connection, all data read from the client 
// is sent back to the client. The read and echo back to the client pattern 
// is continued until the client disconnects.
class Server {
  private int m_numConnections;   // the maximum number of connections the sample is designed to handle simultaneously 
  private int m_receiveBufferSize;// buffer size to use for each socket I/O operation 
  BufferManager m_bufferManager;  // represents a large reusable set of buffers for all socket operations
  const int opsToPreAlloc = 2;    // read, write (don't alloc buffer space for accepts)
  Socket listenSocket;            // the socket used to listen for incoming connection requests
  // pool of reusable SocketAsyncEventArgs objects for write, read and accept socket operations
  SocketAsyncEventArgsPool m_readWritePool;
  int m_totalBytesRead;           // counter of the total # bytes received by the server
  int m_numConnectedSockets;      // the total number of clients connected to the server 
  Semaphore m_maxNumberAcceptedClients;

  // Create an uninitialized server instance.  
  // To start the server listening for connection requests
  // call the Init method followed by Start method 
  //
  // <param name="numConnections">the maximum number of connections the sample is designed to handle simultaneously</param>
  // <param name="receiveBufferSize">buffer size to use for each socket I/O operation</param>
  public Server(int numConnections, int receiveBufferSize) {
    m_totalBytesRead = 0;
    m_numConnectedSockets = 0;
    m_numConnections = numConnections;
    m_receiveBufferSize = receiveBufferSize;
    // allocate buffers such that the maximum number of sockets can have one outstanding read and 
    //write posted to the socket simultaneously  
    m_bufferManager = new BufferManager(receiveBufferSize * numConnections * opsToPreAlloc,
        receiveBufferSize);

    m_readWritePool = new SocketAsyncEventArgsPool(numConnections);
    m_maxNumberAcceptedClients = new Semaphore(numConnections, numConnections); 
  }

  // Initializes the server by preallocating reusable buffers and 
  // context objects.  These objects do not need to be preallocated 
  // or reused, but it is done this way to illustrate how the API can 
  // easily be used to create reusable objects to increase server performance.
  //
  public void Init() {
    // Allocates one large byte buffer which all I/O operations use a piece of.  This gaurds 
    // against memory fragmentation
    m_bufferManager.InitBuffer();

    // preallocate pool of SocketAsyncEventArgs objects
    SocketAsyncEventArgs readWriteEventArg;

    for(int i = 0; i < m_numConnections; i++) {
        //Pre-allocate a set of reusable SocketAsyncEventArgs
        readWriteEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        readWriteEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(IO_Completed);
        readWriteEventArg.UserToken = new AsyncUserToken();
        // assign a byte buffer from the buffer pool to the SocketAsyncEventArg object
        m_bufferManager.SetBuffer(readWriteEventArg);
        // add SocketAsyncEventArg to the pool
        m_readWritePool.Push(readWriteEventArg);
    }
  }

  // Starts the server such that it is listening for 
  // incoming connection requests.    
  //
  // <param name="localEndPoint">The endpoint which the server will listening 
  // for connection requests on</param>
  public void Start(IPEndPoint localEndPoint) {
    // create the socket which listens for incoming connections
    listenSocket = new Socket(localEndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    listenSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);
    // start the server with a listen backlog of 100 connections
    listenSocket.Listen(100);

    // post accepts on the listening socket
    StartAccept(null);            

    //Console.WriteLine("{0} connected sockets with one outstanding receive posted to each....press any key", m_outstandingReadCount);
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to terminate the server process....");
    Console.ReadKey();
  }


  // Begins an operation to accept a connection request from the client 
  //
  // <param name="acceptEventArg">The context object to use when issuing 
  // the accept operation on the server's listening socket</param>
  public void StartAccept(SocketAsyncEventArgs acceptEventArg) {
    if(acceptEventArg == null) {
      acceptEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
      acceptEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(AcceptEventArg_Completed);
    }
    else {
      // socket must be cleared since the context object is being reused
      acceptEventArg.AcceptSocket = null;
    }

    m_maxNumberAcceptedClients.WaitOne();
    bool willRaiseEvent = listenSocket.AcceptAsync(acceptEventArg);
    if (!willRaiseEvent) {
        ProcessAccept(acceptEventArg);
    }
  }

  // This method is the callback method associated with Socket.AcceptAsync 
  // operations and is invoked when an accept operation is complete
  //
  void AcceptEventArg_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e) {
    ProcessAccept(e);
  }

  private void ProcessAccept(SocketAsyncEventArgs e) {
    Interlocked.Increment(ref m_numConnectedSockets);
    Console.WriteLine("Client connection accepted. There are {0} clients connected to the server",
        m_numConnectedSockets);

    // Get the socket for the accepted client connection and put it into the 
    //ReadEventArg object user token
    SocketAsyncEventArgs readEventArgs = m_readWritePool.Pop();
    ((AsyncUserToken)readEventArgs.UserToken).Socket = e.AcceptSocket;

    // As soon as the client is connected, post a receive to the connection
    bool willRaiseEvent = e.AcceptSocket.ReceiveAsync(readEventArgs);
    if(!willRaiseEvent){
        ProcessReceive(readEventArgs);
    }

    // Accept the next connection request
    StartAccept(e);
  }

  // This method is called whenever a receive or send operation is completed on a socket 
  //
  // <param name="e">SocketAsyncEventArg associated with the completed receive operation</param>
  void IO_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e) {
    // determine which type of operation just completed and call the associated handler
    switch (e.LastOperation) {
        case SocketAsyncOperation.Receive:
            ProcessReceive(e);
            break;
        case SocketAsyncOperation.Send:
            ProcessSend(e);
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("The last operation completed on the socket was not a receive or send");
    }    
  }

  // This method is invoked when an asynchronous receive operation completes. 
  // If the remote host closed the connection, then the socket is closed.  
  // If data was received then the data is echoed back to the client.
  //
  private void ProcessReceive(SocketAsyncEventArgs e) {
    // check if the remote host closed the connection
    AsyncUserToken token = (AsyncUserToken)e.UserToken;
    if(e.BytesTransferred > 0 && e.SocketError == SocketError.Success) {
      //increment the count of the total bytes receive by the server
      Interlocked.Add(ref m_totalBytesRead, e.BytesTransferred);
      Console.WriteLine("The server has read a total of {0} bytes", m_totalBytesRead);

      //echo the data received back to the client
      e.SetBuffer(e.Offset, e.BytesTransferred);
      bool willRaiseEvent = token.Socket.SendAsync(e);
      if(!willRaiseEvent) {
        ProcessSend(e);
      }
    }
    else {
      CloseClientSocket(e);
    }
  }

  // This method is invoked when an asynchronous send operation completes.  
  // The method issues another receive on the socket to read any additional 
  // data sent from the client
  //
  // <param name="e"></param>
  private void ProcessSend(SocketAsyncEventArgs e) {
    if(e.SocketError == SocketError.Success) {
      // done echoing data back to the client
      AsyncUserToken token = (AsyncUserToken)e.UserToken;
      // read the next block of data send from the client
      bool willRaiseEvent = token.Socket.ReceiveAsync(e);
      if(!willRaiseEvent) {
        ProcessReceive(e);
      }
    }
    else {
      CloseClientSocket(e);
    }
  }

  private void CloseClientSocket(SocketAsyncEventArgs e) {
    AsyncUserToken token = e.UserToken as AsyncUserToken;
    // close the socket associated with the client
    try {
      token.Socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
    }
    // throws if client process has already closed
    catch (Exception) { }
    token.Socket.Close();

    // decrement the counter keeping track of the total number of clients connected to the server
    Interlocked.Decrement(ref m_numConnectedSockets);

    // Free the SocketAsyncEventArg so they can be reused by another client
    m_readWritePool.Push(e);

    m_maxNumberAcceptedClients.Release();
    Console.WriteLine("A client has been disconnected from the server. There are {0} clients connected to the server", m_numConnectedSockets);
  }
}
```

> **BufferManager**

```
// This class creates a single large buffer which can be divided up 
// and assigned to SocketAsyncEventArgs objects for use with each 
// socket I/O operation.  
// This enables bufffers to be easily reused and guards against 
// fragmenting heap memory.
// 
// The operations exposed on the BufferManager class are not thread safe.
class BufferManager {
  int m_numBytes;                 // the total number of bytes controlled by the buffer pool
  byte[] m_buffer;                // the underlying byte array maintained by the Buffer Manager
  Stack<int> m_freeIndexPool;     // 
  int m_currentIndex;
  int m_bufferSize;

  public BufferManager(int totalBytes, int bufferSize) {
    m_numBytes = totalBytes;
    m_currentIndex = 0;
    m_bufferSize = bufferSize;
    m_freeIndexPool = new Stack<int>();
  }

  // Allocates buffer space used by the buffer pool
  public void InitBuffer() {
    // create one big large buffer and divide that 
    // out to each SocketAsyncEventArg object
    m_buffer = new byte[m_numBytes];
  }

  // Assigns a buffer from the buffer pool to the 
  // specified SocketAsyncEventArgs object
  //
  // <returns>true if the buffer was successfully set, else false</returns>
  public bool SetBuffer(SocketAsyncEventArgs args) {
    if(m_freeIndexPool.Count > 0) {
      args.SetBuffer(m_buffer, m_freeIndexPool.Pop(), m_bufferSize);
    }
    else {
      if((m_numBytes - m_bufferSize) < m_currentIndex) {
        return false;
      }
      args.SetBuffer(m_buffer, m_currentIndex, m_bufferSize);
      m_currentIndex += m_bufferSize;
    }
    return true;
  }

  // Removes the buffer from a SocketAsyncEventArg object.  
  // This frees the buffer back to the buffer pool
  public void FreeBuffer(SocketAsyncEventArgs args) {
    m_freeIndexPool.Push(args.Offset);
    args.SetBuffer(null, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

> **SocketAsyncEventArgsPool**

```
class SocketAsyncEventArgsPool {
  Stack<SocketAsyncEventArgs> m_pool;
  // Initializes the object pool to the specified size
  //
  // The "capacity" parameter is the maximum number of 
  // SocketAsyncEventArgs objects the pool can hold
  public SocketAsyncEventArgsPool(int capacity) {
    m_pool = new Stack<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(capacity);
  }

  // Add a SocketAsyncEventArg instance to the pool
  //
  //The "item" parameter is the SocketAsyncEventArgs instance 
  // to add to the pool
  public void Push(SocketAsyncEventArgs item) {
    if(item == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("Items added to a SocketAsyncEventArgsPool cannot be null"); }
    lock(m_pool) {
        m_pool.Push(item);
    }
  }

  // Removes a SocketAsyncEventArgs instance from the pool
  // and returns the object removed from the pool
  public SocketAsyncEventArgs Pop() {
    lock(m_pool) {
      return m_pool.Pop();
    }
  }

  // The number of SocketAsyncEventArgs instances in the pool
  public int Count {
    get { return m_pool.Count; }
  }
}
```

> **AsyncUserToken**

```
internal class AsyncUserToken {

  private Socket _socket;
  public Socket Socket {
    get => this._socket;
    set => this._socket = value;
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите ссылку на пример от Microsoft.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: У Google Chrome максимально 10 одновременно открытых сокетов, поэтому вы и не можете на нем больше параллельных потоков выжать.

Comment: ГеннадийП, вопрос же не по Google Chrome, я просто заметил что он не грузит когда я пытаюсь до своего сервера нафлудить больше 16000 соединений, сервер на C# клиент тоже C# а Google Chrome просто был открыт и я заметил что он не грузит

Comment: @MikeWaters Как вы определили что он держит не больше 16000 соединений? Под какую разрядность собран сервер: х86 или х64?

Comment: Если бороться за производительность, тем более в сетевом окружении, то разумно выбрать чистый `С` для транспорта, и какую либо эвент обвязку, например `libUW`, библиотек много, можно подобрать по вкусу.

Comment: @NewView не могу, он в WPF)

Comment: @ГеннадийП добавил скрины

Comment: нашел это https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/196271/when-you-try-to-connect-from-tcp-ports-greater-than-5000-you-receive-t сейчас попробую

Comment: ну проблема лимита какбы решена, а вот со скоростю получения запросов ничего не нашел